# Custom in-app billing for avoiding Android/iTunes transactions fees

Tags: iphone, android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

We are planning a new application development for iPhone and Android devices. The application would be published in both markets (Android Market and Apple's App Store) and its download would be free.
Nevertheless, the application would have some items that can be purchased by the user. The easiest way would be to integrate each version with its corresponding billing system: Android In-App Billing and the Apple iTunes Billing System.

Is there a way for avoiding the 30% transaction fee from the billing systems? Can a developer use a custom in-app billing system for its application? Is there a disclaimer policy for Android or iPhone when using other in-app bill systems for avoiding their transaction fees? What are the options a developer has for providing an in-app item purchase within his application?

Many thanks!

Comment: The Android/iPhone in-app billing systems are valid for digital content: photos, game levels, game items, etc. According to the iOS In App Purchase Guide or Android In-App Billing Program, an application is not allowed for selling real-world services. OK, then the question right now would be: can I sell real-world services within an iPhone/Android application published in the App Store/Android Market using a custom billing web page??

Comment: There are many applications selling tickets for cinema, gigs, theatre... and the users are buying those tickets directly from the phone app filling in his credit card details. Are those applications paying any transaction fee? I don't think so, am I right?

Comment: Hi Sergi, are custom billing systems via an in-app webpage permitted? (I was thinking a paypal webpage or something to avoid the huge 30% Apple cuts)..any advice would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

We've developed several applications that transport users to a web page payment portal contained within the application.

Apple have seemed fine with this approach, in one particular application we had implemented both In-App purchasing and a custom payment portal - they asked us to remove In-App purchasing as the app was selling deal/vouchers and they classed this as virtual product.... they didn't reject anything about our custom payment portal.

Potentially they could pull all apps that do this at any point they feel like it, although I don't see this as a likely scenario.

Comment: Thanks Adam! I thought about the billing custom webpage as well, I guess it's the best approach. Would this solution be valid for Android as well?? Do this approach fit with Android Distribution agreement?

Comment: Whereas non digital content, like real-world services, is not allowed to be sold through the iOS In-App or Android In-App Billing programs: can a real-world service be purchased from a iPhone or Android application, published in its corresponding Market (AppStore or Android Market), using this custom payment portal approach??

Comment: Realistically you need an attorney to answer these kinds of questions. My non-attorney opinion is the EULA's are only concerned with the model that the user is purchasing the app itself, or that the app has no true purpose if this side payment isn't made. In the case of purchasing actual items I don't believe either market expects to get a 30% (or any) cut.

Comment: @sergi if you don't pay to Google, I would guess it's prohibited.

Answer (score 3):

Since both Android Market and Apple's App Store terms of service prohibit what you're asking for, the answer is a simple: no, there is no way to avoid the transaction fees (and still remain within the terms of service).

You're also asking about a disclaimer policy -- if you mean for your product, you should disclaim to your users that your app could get removed from its respective market at any time, without any notice (if you decide to implement billing that subverts the market).

Comment: I trust you but I'm unable to find the terms of service for both platforms regarding the obligatory of using their own billing system for in-app purchases. Can you tell me the link?

Comment: On the other hand, what about the PayPal API?? I think there is a PayPal API for iPhone providing in-app payments, Am I right?

Comment: All Google says about payment processors in the distribution agreement (http://www.android.com/us/developer-distribution-agreement.html) is: "Payment Processor(s): Any party authorized by Google to provide payment processing services that enable Developers with optional Payment Accounts to charge Device users for Products distributed via the Market." Of course, it is highly unlikely that Google will authorise a payment processor and *not* get their 30% so in essence, @mah is correct, you would be violating the terms of your distribution agreement with Google.